# task.getResult() throwes a java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Storage 19.1.1 and
Firebase Database 19.2.1

I am using what is recommended by too many developers in order to retrieve the Uri of an image stored in the firebase storage, this my code:

```
uploadTask.continueWith(new Continuation()
                {
                    @Override
                    public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception
                    {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            progressDialog.cancel();
                            Toast.makeText(FriendsChatActivity.this, ErrorOcc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task)
                    {
                        Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult();
                        myUrl = downloadUrl.toString();

                        Map messagePictureBody = new HashMap();
                            messagePictureBody.put("message", myUrl);
                            messagePictureBody.put("type", checker);
                            messagePictureBody.put("from", messageSenderID);
                            messagePictureBody.put("to", messageReceiverID);
                            messagePictureBody.put("messageID", messagePushID);
                            messagePictureBody.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
                            messagePictureBody.put("date", saveCurrentDate);

                        Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
                        messageBodyDetails.put(messageSenderRef + "/" + messagePushID, messagePictureBody);
                        messageBodyDetails.put(messageReceiverRef + "/" + messagePushID, messagePictureBody);

                        RootRef.child("Users").child(messageSenderID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                fromName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                online = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                                progressDialog.cancel();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                            {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

And my Error is this:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.eiskalterfreund.chweppen, PID: 520
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu cannot be cast to android.net.Uri
        at com.eiskalterfreund.chweppen.FriendsActivities.FriendsChatActivity$10.onComplete(FriendsChatActivity.java:562)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata() != null) {
            if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference() != null) {
                Task<Uri> result = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        String imageUrl = uri.toString();
                        //createNewPost(imageUrl);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }});
```

Comment: I'm getting the file URL

Comment: While this solution answered the question, code blocks on their own are not usually useful also for future visitors. It's recommended to explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: @AlexMamo  I remember in my future.

Comment: @Eiskalter Freund if you find this answer useful please upmark it also thanks you.